# How do I setup the development environment for cappuccino on windows 7

Tags: cappuccino

How do I install Cappuccino in Windows. The sample app doesn't run. Cant get to run the shell script.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is modern browsers require a web server to work rather than allowing the index.html file to run by itself. So you will need to set up a local web server on your Windows machine to serve the sample app, and then navigate to it. Once that's done you can simply edit the sample app to create your app - it's a complete Cappuccino install.